# Nisse Server: Part 3 Stream Layer

Tags: c++, io, c++14, stream

Getting close to a release of generic server.

[Nisse Server: Part 1 Helper Functions](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/168767/507)
[Nisse Server: Part 2 Socket Layer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/168771/507)

Here is the stream layer code.

This basically provides a `std::istream` and `std::ostream` wrapper around a `DataSocket`. This allowing you to use normal C++ stream operations on a socket.

One notable non-standard part are the two callbacks that are passed to the constructors.

```
    Notifier                noAvailableData;
    Notifier                flushing;
```

These are used by higher level code. So that when flushing or no data is available we get a callback to the higher level code. This is what allows the current code to yield back to main loop if there was a writing/read operation that would block.

i.e. If any write/read operation would block we go and find another socket that is currently available and execute its code.

#### SocketStream.h

```
#ifndef THORSANVIL_SIMPLE_STREAM_THOR_STREAM_H
#define THORSANVIL_SIMPLE_STREAM_THOR_STREAM_H

#include "Socket.h"
#include <istream>
#include <vector>

namespace ThorsAnvil
{
    namespace Socket
    {

using Notifier = std::function<void()>;

class SocketStreamBuffer: public std::streambuf
{
    private:
        typedef std::streambuf::traits_type traits;
        typedef traits::int_type            int_type;
        typedef traits::char_type           char_type;

        DataSocket&             stream;
        Notifier                noAvailableData;
        Notifier                flushing;
        std::vector<char>       buffer;

    public:
        virtual ~SocketStreamBuffer() override;
        SocketStreamBuffer(DataSocket& stream, Notifier noAvailableData, Notifier flushing, std::vector<char>&& bufData = std::vector<char>(4000), char const* currentStart = nullptr, char const* currentEnd = nullptr);
        SocketStreamBuffer(SocketStreamBuffer&& move) noexcept;

    protected:
        virtual int_type        underflow() override;
        virtual std::streamsize xsgetn(char_type* s, std::streamsize count) override;

        virtual int_type        overflow(int_type ch = traits::eof()) override;
        virtual std::streamsize xsputn(char_type const* s,std::streamsize count) override;
};

class ISocketStream: public std::istream
{
    SocketStreamBuffer buffer;

    public:
        ISocketStream(DataSocket& stream, Notifier noAvailableData, Notifier flushing, std::vector<char>&& bufData, char const* currentStart, char const* currentEnd);
        ISocketStream(DataSocket& stream, Notifier noAvailableData, Notifier flushing);
        ISocketStream(ISocketStream&& move) noexcept;
};

class OSocketStream: public std::ostream
{
    SocketStreamBuffer buffer;

    public:
        OSocketStream(DataSocket& stream, Notifier noAvailableData, Notifier flushing);
        OSocketStream(OSocketStream&& move) noexcept;
};

    }
}

#endif
```

#### SocketStream.cpp

```
#include "SocketStream.h"

using namespace ThorsAnvil::Socket;

SocketStreamBuffer::SocketStreamBuffer(DataSocket& stream, Notifier noAvailableData, Notifier flushing, std::vector<char>&& bufData, char const* currentStart, char const* currentEnd)
    : stream(stream)
    , noAvailableData(noAvailableData)
    , flushing(flushing)
    , buffer(std::move(bufData))
{
    char* newStart = const_cast<char*>(currentStart);
    char* newEnd   = const_cast<char*>(currentEnd);
    if (newStart == nullptr || newEnd == nullptr)
    {
        newStart = &buffer[0];
        newEnd   = &buffer[0];
    }

    setg(&buffer[0], newStart, newEnd);
    setp(&buffer[0], &buffer[buffer.size() - 1]);
}

SocketStreamBuffer::SocketStreamBuffer(SocketStreamBuffer&& move) noexcept
    : stream(move.stream)
    , noAvailableData(move.noAvailableData)
    , buffer(std::move(move.buffer))
{
    move.setg(nullptr, nullptr, nullptr);
    move.setp(nullptr, nullptr);
}

SocketStreamBuffer::~SocketStreamBuffer()
{
    overflow();
}

SocketStreamBuffer::int_type SocketStreamBuffer::underflow()
{
    /*
     * Ensures that at least one character is available in the input area by updating the pointers to the input area (if needed)
     * and reading more data in from the input sequence (if applicable).
     * Returns the value of that character (converted to int_type with Traits::to_int_type(c)) on success or Traits::eof() on failure.
     * The function may update gptr, egptr and eback pointers to define the location of newly loaded data (if any).
     * On failure, the function ensures that either gptr() == nullptr or gptr() == egptr.
     * The base class version of the function does nothing. The derived classes may override this function to allow updates to the get area in the case of exhaustion.
     */

    while (gptr() == egptr())
    {
        bool    moreData;
        size_t  count;
        std::tie(moreData, count) = stream.getMessageData(&buffer[0], buffer.size());
        if (moreData && count == 0)
        {
            noAvailableData();
        }
        else if (count != 0)
        {
            setg(&buffer[0], &buffer[0], &buffer[count]);
        }
        else if (!moreData)
        {
            break;
        }
    }
    return (gptr() == egptr()) ? traits::eof() : traits::to_int_type(*gptr());
}

std::streamsize SocketStreamBuffer::xsgetn(char_type* dest, std::streamsize count)
{
    /*
     * Reads count characters from the input sequence and stores them into a character array pointed to by s.
     * The characters are read as if by repeated calls to sbumpc().
     * That is, if less than count characters are immediately available, the function calls uflow() to provide more until traits::eof() is returned.
     * Classes derived from std::basic_streambuf are permitted to provide more efficient implementations of this function.
     */

    std::streamsize currentBufferSize = egptr() - gptr();
    std::streamsize movedCharacter    = std::min(count, currentBufferSize);
    std::copy(gptr(), gptr() + movedCharacter, dest);

    dest  += movedCharacter;
    count -= movedCharacter;

    while (count > 0)
    {
        bool    moreData;
        size_t  dataRead;
        std::tie(moreData, dataRead) = stream.getMessageData(dest, count);
        if (moreData && dataRead == 0)
        {
            noAvailableData();
        }
        else if (!moreData)
        {
            break;
        }
        dest  += dataRead;
        count -= dataRead;
        movedCharacter += dataRead;
    }
    return movedCharacter;
}

SocketStreamBuffer::int_type SocketStreamBuffer::overflow(int_type ch)
{
    /*
     * Ensures that there is space at the put area for at least one character by saving some initial subsequence of
     * characters starting at pbase() to the output sequence and updating the pointers to the put area (if needed).
     * If ch is not Traits::eof() (i.e. Traits::eq_int_type(ch, Traits::eof()) != true),
     *     it is either put to the put area or directly saved to the output sequence.
     * The function may update pptr, epptr and pbase pointers to define the location to write more data.
     * On failure, the function ensures that either pptr() == nullptr or pptr() == epptr.
     * The base class version of the function does nothing. The derived classes may override this function to allow
     * updates to the put area in the case of exhaustion.
     */

    if (ch != traits::eof())
    {
        /* Note: When we set the "put" pointers we delibrately leave an extra space that is not buffer.
         * When overflow is called the normal buffer is used up, but there is an extra space in the real
         * underlying buffer that we can use.
         *
         * So: *pptr = ch; // will never fail.
         */
        *pptr() = ch;
        pbump(1);
    }

    flushing();
    std::streamsize toWrite = pptr() - pbase();
    std::streamsize written = 0;
    while (toWrite != written)
    {
        bool        moreSpace;
        std::size_t count;
        std::tie(moreSpace, count) = stream.putMessageData(pbase(), pptr() - pbase(), written);
        if (moreSpace && count == 0)
        {
            noAvailableData();
        }
        else if (moreSpace)
        {
            written += count;
        }
        else
        {
            return traits::eof();
        }
    }
    setp(&buffer[0], &buffer[buffer.size() - 1]);
    return written;
}

std::streamsize SocketStreamBuffer::xsputn(char_type const* source, std::streamsize count)
{
    std::streamsize written = 0;
    if (epptr() - pptr() > count)
    {
        // If we have space in the internal buffer then just place it there.
        std::copy(source, source + count, pptr());
        pbump(count);
        written = count;
    }
    else
    {
        // Not enough room in the internal buffer.
        // So write everything to the output stream.
        if (overflow() != traits::eof())
        {
            while (count != written)
            {
                bool        moreSpace;
                std::size_t dataWritten;
                std::tie(moreSpace, dataWritten) = stream.putMessageData(source, count, written);
                if (moreSpace && dataWritten == 0)
                {
                    noAvailableData();
                }
                else if (moreSpace)
                {
                    written += dataWritten;
                }
                else
                {
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return written;
}
// ------------------------

ISocketStream::ISocketStream(DataSocket& stream, Notifier noAvailableData, Notifier flushing)
    : std::istream(nullptr)
    , buffer(stream, noAvailableData, flushing)
{
    std::istream::rdbuf(&buffer);
}

ISocketStream::ISocketStream(DataSocket& stream, Notifier noAvailableData, Notifier flushing, std::vector<char>&& bufData, char const* currentStart, char const* currentEnd)
    : std::istream(nullptr)
    , buffer(stream, noAvailableData, flushing, std::move(bufData), currentStart, currentEnd)
{
    rdbuf(&buffer);
}

ISocketStream::ISocketStream(ISocketStream&& move) noexcept
    : std::istream(nullptr)
    , buffer(std::move(move.buffer))
{
    rdbuf(&buffer);
}

// ------------------------

OSocketStream::OSocketStream(DataSocket& stream, Notifier noAvailableData, Notifier flushing)
    : std::ostream(nullptr)
    , buffer(stream, noAvailableData, flushing)
{
    rdbuf(&buffer);
}

OSocketStream::OSocketStream(OSocketStream&& move) noexcept
    : std::ostream(nullptr)
    , buffer(std::move(move.buffer))
{
    rdbuf(&buffer);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

1. Looks like [Single Entry, Single Exit](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/118703/where-did-the-notion-of-one-return-only-come-from) got you good.

   Not only does that lead to more complicated source-code, but also to possibly slightly bigger and less efficient compiled code.
2. Try to handle the most likely case first in an `if`-`else if`-`else`-chain.

   It's often marginally more efficient, and in `SocketStreamBuffer::underflow()` even shorter.
3. Using control-flow-statements often allows you to reduce nesting.

```
while (gptr() == egptr())
{
    bool moreData;
    size_t count;
    std::tie(moreData, count) = stream.getMessageData(&buffer[0], buffer.size());
    if (count != 0)
    {
        setg(&buffer[0], &buffer[0], &buffer[count]);
        break;
    }
    else if (!moreData)
    {
        return traits::eof();
    }
    noAvailableData();
}
return traits::to_int_type(*gptr());
```

4. In `SocketStreamBuffer::xsgetn()` you call `std::copy()` using InputIt, Count, and OutputIt. Why do that contortion instead of using `std::copy_n()`? At least the compiler should fix the compiled code.
5. You forgot to modify the get-area in `SocketStreamBuffer::xsgetn()`.
6. You mishandle `!moreData && dataRead` by discarding the last read bytes.
7. If `SocketStreamBuffer::overflow()` is only ever called when the buffer is full, it works. You also call it in the dtor and the class could be subclassed, so please re-read the requirements for `overflow()` in the failure-case, for example here: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_streambuf/overflow
8. Your `.overflow()` is more appropriate for `.sync()`. And you should call `.sync()` in the dtor instead.
9. You should re-read how your `DataSocket::putMessageData` uses its third argument. You are misusing it, leading to a bug.
10. You should only get directly into / put directly from a user-supplied buffer in `xsgetn()` / `xsputn()` if the free space in it is a very significant fraction of your stream-buffers internal buffer, or you use vectored IO. Unbuffered small-request IO is really quite inefficient.
11. Why do you only allow setting a custom buffer for `ISocketStream` but not for `OSocketStream`?

Comment: Can't figure out this: `You mishandle !moreData && dataRead by discarding the last read bytes.`

Comment: I can't quite spot the bug you mention: `You should re-read how your DataSocket::putMessageData uses its third argument. You are misusing it, leading to a bug.`

Comment: See `xsgetn()` for the case `!moreData && dataRead`. See `xsputn()` or `overflow()`, you are adding the combined read amount to the amount read before the call to `putMessageData()`, so in effect `written = 2 * written + written_now`.