# Nisse Server: Part 6 SimpleProtocol

Tags: c++, c++14

Getting close to a release of generic server.

[Nisse Server: Part 1 Helper Functions](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/168767/507)
[Nisse Server: Part 2 Socket Layer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/168771/507)
[Nisse Server: Part 3 Stream Layer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/168772/507)
[Nisse Server: Part 4 Server](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/168790/507)
[Nisse Server: Part 5 Handler](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/168792/507)

As a demonstration protocol (also for testing). Here is a class that pulls it all together. With this we can have a function server that implements the "Simple Protocol".

The "Simple Protocol" (is something I invented for testing) is simply this.

```
Request  : RequBody
RequBody : <8 bytes Size object><Message of Correct Size>

Response : RespBody
RespBody : <8 bytes Size object><The request Body with " -> OK <-" appeneded>
```

Note: This is not HTTP or anything based on it.

Here we are using `boost/coroutine` that allows us to return control to the main function (trying to avoid using the term thread).

The `CoRoutine` object `worker` does all the work. When you call `worker()` control is transferred to the `CoRoutine`. When the code in worker invokes `yield()` the call to `worker()` returns. The difference is that the next time `worker()` is called control returns to the point where it previously `yielded from`, so to the lambda it looks like the call to `yield()` just returned.

This allows us to wrap the `yield()` into a lambda and pass it to the `[IO]SocketStream` object so that when a read/write would block we actually yield back to the main routine.

This is designed to test that on large requests that a read will not block and return to the main event loop and potentially get data from another socket while it waits.

#### ProtocolSimpleStreamNisse.h

```
#ifndef THORSANVIL_NISSE_PROTOCOL_SIMPLE_STREAM_NISSE_H
#define THORSANVIL_NISSE_PROTOCOL_SIMPLE_STREAM_NISSE_H

#include "NisseHandler.h"
#include "SocketStream.h"
#include <boost/coroutine/asymmetric_coroutine.hpp>

namespace ThorsAnvil
{
    namespace Nisse
    {
        namespace ProtocolSimple
        {

using CoRoutine = boost::coroutines::asymmetric_coroutine<void>::pull_type;
using Yield     = boost::coroutines::asymmetric_coroutine<void>::push_type;

class Message
{
    public:
        std::size_t     size;
        std::string     message;
    public:
        Message() = default;
        Message(Message&& move)
            : size(std::move(move.size))
            , message(std::move(move.message))
        {}
        friend std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& stream, Message& info)
        {
            if (stream.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&info.size), sizeof(info.size)))
            {
                info.message.resize(info.size);
                stream.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&info.message[0]), info.size);
            }
            return stream;
        }
        friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& stream, Message& info)
        {
            info.size = info.message.size();
            if (stream.write(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&info.size), sizeof(info.size)))
            {
                stream.write(&info.message[0], info.size);
            }
            return stream;
        }
};

class ReadMessageStreamHandler: public NisseHandler
{
    private:
        CoRoutine       worker;
    public:
        ReadMessageStreamHandler(NisseService& parent, LibEventBase* base, ThorsAnvil::Socket::DataSocket&& socket);
        virtual void eventActivate(LibSocketId sockId, short eventType) override;
};

class WriteMessageStreamHandler: public NisseHandler
{
    private:
        CoRoutine       worker;
    public:
        WriteMessageStreamHandler(NisseService& parent, LibEventBase* base, ThorsAnvil::Socket::DataSocket&& socket, Message&& message);
        virtual void eventActivate(LibSocketId sockId, short eventType) override;
};

        }
    }
}

#endif
```

#### ProtocolSimpleStreamNisse.cpp

```
#include "ProtocolSimpleStreamNisse.h"
#include "NisseService.h"

using namespace ThorsAnvil::Nisse::ProtocolSimple;

ReadMessageStreamHandler::ReadMessageStreamHandler(NisseService& parent, LibEventBase* base, ThorsAnvil::Socket::DataSocket&& so)
    : NisseHandler(parent, base, so.getSocketId(), EV_READ)
    , worker([&parent = *this, socket = std::move(so)](Yield& yield) mutable
                {
                    Socket::ISocketStream   stream(socket, [&yield](){yield();}, [](){});
                    Message                 message;
                    yield();

                    stream >> message;
                    parent.moveHandler<WriteMessageStreamHandler>(std::move(socket), std::move(message));
                }
            )
{}

void ReadMessageStreamHandler::eventActivate(LibSocketId /*sockId*/, short /*eventType*/)
{
    worker();
}

WriteMessageStreamHandler::WriteMessageStreamHandler(NisseService& parent, LibEventBase* base, ThorsAnvil::Socket::DataSocket&& so, Message&& ms)
    : NisseHandler(parent, base, so.getSocketId(), EV_WRITE)
    , worker([&parent = *this, socket = std::move(so), message = std::move(ms)](Yield& yield) mutable
                {
                    Socket::OSocketStream   stream(socket, [&yield](){yield();}, [](){});
                    yield();

                    message.message += " -> OK <-";
                    stream << message;
                    parent.dropHandler();
                }
            )
{}

void WriteMessageStreamHandler::eventActivate(LibSocketId /*sockId*/, short /*eventType*/)
{
    worker();
}
```

#### Nisse.pp

```
#include "NisseService.h"
#include "ProtocolSimpleStreamNisse.h"
#include "NisseHandler.h"

#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    try
    {
        using ThorsAnvil::Nisse::NisseService;

        NisseService    service;

        using ThorsAnvil::Nisse::ProtocolSimple::ReadMessageStreamHandler;
        service.listenOn<ReadMessageStreamHandler>(40718);
        service.listenOn<ReadMessageStreamHandler>(40719);
        service.listenOn<ReadMessageStreamHandler>(40720);
        service.listenOn<ReadMessageStreamHandler>(40721);

        service.start();
    }
    catch (std::exception const& e)
    {
        //Log exception
        throw;
    }
    catch (...)
    {
        //Log exception
        throw;
    }
}
```

#### Building:

If you put together all the source in the last 6 articles and compile together with `-levent` it should build an executable.

External requirements. [libevent](http://libevent.org/) and [Boost Co-Routines](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_64_0/libs/coroutine/doc/html/index.html)

I have a github project with all this code that I will make public when I have finished up a couple of more things.

But until then I have provided everything you need to build an executable I think (let me know if anything goes wrong).